# iText nested splitting

Tags: split, itext

Let's assume that I have some text and I want to display it in PDF. My text consists of non-splittable parts (e.g. each of them has length 3). 
For example, if i have `AAABBBCCC` and only 4 letters fit to the line, then text will be

`AAA
BBB
CCC`

Sometimes it happens that braces occurs in the text. In this case I want

- If **(%content%)** fits to the line, that print it as is
- If **(%content%)** doesn't fit to a current line but does to the next line, then move it to the next line and print as is
- If **(%content%)** doesn't fit to a current line and doesn't fit to the next line, then move it to the next line and split **only** between 3-letters parts.

So my logic look like the next:

- open brace is splittable character (a text can be splitted before the brace only)
- if the content inside braces including them doesn't fit to the line, then first letters of 3-symbols parts are splittable.

The problem is that I can't catch how to build such nested splitting logic.
So for example if text is `AAA(AAABBBCCC)` and only 5 letters fit to the line
then result should be

`AAA
(AAA
BBB
CCC)`

instead of

`AAA
(AAAB
BBCCC
)`

Comment: Have you tried using zero-width spaces at the preferred split positions?

Comment: Also, I would think that implementing the split character interface would do the trick. I don't see any code though, so I can't tell if this is an iText 5 or an iText 7 question (and the answer is very different depending on whether the old, unsupported iText 5 or the new iText 7 version is used).